# C# WPF Как отследить double click на ListBoxItem?

Tags: c#, wpf

MouseDoubleClick работает и когда нажимаю вне  ListBoxItem. Как проверить точный double click на ListBoxItem?

Comment: Вы издеваетесь что ли? Я вам под вашим прошлым вопросом давал ссылку на топик с этим вопросом.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, да, я смотрел, но мне тогда был важен interactivity)